# How to format date time on inner Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 fetch('http://localhost:8082/list/findbyid/'+id+'/'+productid)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            const tableBody = document.getElementById('dataInven');
            data.forEach(user => {
              const row = document.createElement('tr');
              row.innerHTML = `
                <td>${user.procode}</td>
                <td>${user.proname}</td>
                <td>${user.unit}</td>
                <td>${user.cat_name}</td>
                <td>${user.quantity}</td>
                <td>${user.update_by}</td>
                <td>${user.update_date}</td>
              `;
              tableBody.appendChild(row);
            });
            
          });
```

this is my inner data that I query from API and after that my **update_date** Show Like this **2023-05-12T09:14:34.742+00:00**
But want only **2023-05-15 09:14:34 am**

Comment: Consider using a ready to use package like i.e: https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns

Comment: And please learn the difference between Java and JavaScript

Comment: how can i show oh my td

Answer (score 0):

By using [date-fns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns) you can use [`.format()`](https://date-fns.org/v2.30.0/docs/format) like:

```html
<script type="module">
import { format } from 'https://esm.run/date-fns';
const someDate = "2023-05-12T09:14:34.742+00:00";
const dateFormatted = format(new Date(someDate), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
console.log(dateFormatted);
</script>
```

will output: `2023-14-12 11:14:34 AM`